# Anyone know if it's possible to use custom sounds on the iTouch piezo speaker?

Tags: iphone

I'm obviously not trying to play full spectrum audio, but is there some way to customize the iPhone/iTouch system alert sounds to play a little melody on the piezo speaker?  The functionality is clearly present, so I guess the question is has Apple made it available for developer use...

Thanks,
-S

Comment: Sigh, alright.  Do you know where I can find a list of all the available sounds that can be made?  I know there's at least the 'click' that plays on unlock and the little alert melody that 'chess with friends' uses

Comment: oh I guess they're in the sounds settings menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It isn't.  Sorry.

Only thing you can do from an application is this (you can use any SoundID for this, really):

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

> **Discussion**
>
> Depending on the particular iPhone OS device, this function plays a short sound and may invoke vibration. Calling this function does the following on various iPhone OS devices:
>
> iPhone—plays the specified sound and, if the user has configured the Settings application for vibration on ring, invokes vibration.
>
> iPod touch, original—plays a short alert melody.
>
> iPod touch, 2nd generation—plays the specified sound.

Comment: It seems like the only defined kSystemSoundID is Vibrate...do you know how to access the other sounds? ("New Mail", "Sent Mail", "Calendar Alerts" sounds, etc)

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few predefined sounds you can use in the 0-2000 range. For example, the keyboard click can be called like such:

```
AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(1104);
```

There is also a way to play a custom melody on the first-generation iPod touch, but it's not pretty.